# Select Some Columns and Delete Others VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to select columns with only certain titles, deleting all the others, but I keep getting an error. It is a `Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed`, and it highlights the seventh line of code (`Range(Cells(1, Col)).Select`).
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated-- thanks!

```
       Dim Col As Integer
        Col = 1
        Range("A1").Select
        While Selection.Value <> ""
            If Selection.Value = "A" Then
                Col = Col + 1
                Range(Cells(1, Col)).Select
            ElseIf Selection.Value = "B" Then
                Col = Col + 1
                Range(Cells(1, Col)).Select
            ElseIf Selection.Value = "D" Then
                Col = Col + 1
                Range(Cells(1, Col)).Select
            ElseIf Selection.Value = "E" Then
                Col = Col + 1
                Range(Cells(1, Col)).Select
            ElseIf Selection.Value = "F" Then
                Col = Col + 1
                Range(Cells(1, Col)).Select
            ElseIf Selection.Value = "H" Then
                Col = Col + 1
                Range(Cells(1, Col)).Select
            ElseIf Selection.Value = "J" Then
                Col = Col + 1
                Range(Cells(1, Col)).Select
            ElseIf Selection.Value = "M" Then
                Col = Col + 1
                Range(Cells(1, Col)).Select
            ElseIf Selection.Value = "N" Then
                Col = Col + 1
                Range(Cells(1, Col)).Select
            ElseIf Selection.Value = "P" Then
                Col = Col + 1
                Range(Cells(1, Col)).Select
            ElseIf Selection.Value = "R" Then
                Col = Col + 1
                Range(Cells(1, Col)).Select
            ElseIf Selection.Value = "S" Then
                Col = Col + 1
                Range(Cells(1, Col)).Select
            ElseIf Selection.Value = "T" Then
                Col = Col + 1
                Range(Cells(1, Col)).Select
            ElseIf Selection.Value = "V" Then
                Col = Col + 1
                Range(Cells(1, Col)).Select
            ElseIf Selection.Value = "X" Then
                Col = Col + 1
                Range(Cells(1, Col)).Select
            Else: ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Delete
            End If
        Wend
```

Comment: Try getting rid of the `Range`, so just use `Cells(1, Col).Select`.

Comment: Thanks-- that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the error is caused by calling Range with only one Cell argument.  If you have only one Cell, you must append the Cell with its Address property, so the line should be `Range(Cells(1,col).Address).Select`

Secondly, from what you've described you would like your code to do, I don't think this code will actually perform how you'd like.  Frankly, I can't really tell what it is you are even trying to do from the code itself, so be forewarned that my answer will fix the error call, but it seems likely that it won't run as you are anticipating once it does run.

Comment: At the very least, there is definitely a much more efficient way to run this code, if it is actually written as you intend for it to run

Comment: Thanks-- that worked!
Additionally, I just inserted letters as column names so that the emphasis would be on the problem, but that may have just confused things-- anyway, it does work now, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Also you can easily shorten the if statement as well by including `or` in your question part.

```
With Selection
    If .Value = "A" or "B" or...  ...Then...

    Else...

    End If
End With
```

Hope this helps - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx

Comment: Saves you having to write out a billion if statements xD